# A Preposition Question

Tags: prepositions

> "Tempe police show reporters more body cam footage *in fatal shooting
>   of boy with air soft gun.*"

What does the "in" in the sentence mean? "Pertaining to" or "in the event of"?

If it means "pertaining to", does the following sentence make sense?

> "The journalist dug out more news reports *in the murder that happened
>   20 years ago.*"

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

As for the murder sentence, there is a literal way of reading that which says the news reports were somehow on the murder scene, but it's obvious from the construction of the sentence that "in" means "on" or "about" or as previously noted "pertaining to," "regarding," et cetera.

Both make sense.

Note that the bodycam footage actually was at the fatal shooting. So that is more literally correct. So although the news reports sentence is less concise, well, it does make sense.